# Carthage issue: failed with exit code 128

Tags: git, github, swift3, xcode8, carthage

I am migrating from Swift 1.2 to Swift 3.0. I am using Carthage to handle my 3rd party frameworks. When i try to update my Carthage in my Mac terminal using the command

```
carthage update
```

I am ending up with this error

`A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.git /Users/karthikeya/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/TTTAttributedLabel) failed with exit code 128:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out`

The 3rd party frameworks i am using are 
SnapKit,
ramy-kfoury/SwiftRouter,
TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel,
realm/realm-cocoa,
matthewpalmer/Locksmith,
Alamofire/Alamofire,
Alamofire/AlamofireImage,

I tried using different commands on similar lines like

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

and also this

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

But all of these give me the same result. I am breaking my head over this.

I did a little research and some people suggested it might be a proxy issue. I ran these commands in terminal

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Still no luck with carthage update. Someone please tell me what is happening? Why is the Carthage not updating?

I cleaned cache using this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
```

Even quit Xcode and restarted my system.

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Comment: I haven't found a proper solution to this. But a work around is to use different versions of these 3rd party libraries in our application.

Answer (score 4):

Following step helped me with very similar carthage error (code 128, but other details):

1. close xcode, close other git-client apps (SourceTree)
2. run `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit`
3. restart mac
4. run `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`

After it carthage successfully built dependencies.

Later I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42935039/4322841) seems may be related. But I did not use it.